# Set a mobile marker for google maps in ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, google-maps-markers

I'm doing an uber type application with ionic 2.
I already get my geolocation and I put a marker.
But I need to locate a movable marker that when moving the cell also moves. If I point the cell to any position, on the map show me that position. The marker should show where I pointed or where I am going.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to google people and there is not a google api that can do this. Since it is only allowed for native versions. I was told that there are pages that do similar things or just create a gift to make the waves or create a compass and paint it on the map.

Thank you very much